# Bootstrap Popover Content Not Showing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, popover

Hi i am using Tiva Event Calendar which generates the HTML from JS in a separate file.

I am using a popover on date box in calendar with data coming from database on my index.html where the calendar.js is also included.

I am having trouble showing popover content. I am creating the content div in

calendar.js file and initiating the popover on index.html.

If i use a static content for popover it shows up but if i use the getPopContent() function it does not.

Either my JS to generate the popover HTML is not working or function is loading before the content.

I have spent the whole day but could not figure it out.

Please help. Thanks

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

calendarString += '<div id=\"'+ events[t].id +'-content\" style=\"display:none;\"></div>';
              
           $(events[t].id + "-content").html('<div class="event-tooltip-item">'
            + '<div class="event-name">' + events[t].name + '</div>'
            + '<div class="event-image">' + events[t].image + '</div>'
            + '<div class="event-intro">' + getShortText(events[t].description, 10) + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
           );


calendarString += '<div class=\"calendar-event-name event-60 pop ' + event_class + ' color-' + color + '\" id=\"' + events[t].id + '\" ><span class="event-image"><img src="admin/event/images/' + events[t].image + '" alt="' + events[t].name + '" /></span><a class="event-name">'+ events[t].name +'</a><\/div>';
            }
}


$(window).load(function () {
   var popOverSettings = {
              placement: 'left',
              container: 'body',
              html: true,
              trigger: "manual",
              /*content: function () {
                  return $('#popover-content').html();
              }*/
              content: function () {
                  getPopContent($(this).prop("id"))
              }
          }

      $(".pop").each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          

          var $pElem= $this;
          $pElem.popover(popOverSettings).on("mouseenter", function () {
              var _this = this;
              $(this).addClass("grayscale").fadeTo(400,0.8);
              $(this).popover("show");
              $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                  $(_this).popover('hide');
              });
          }).on("mouseleave", function () {
              var _this = this;
              $(this).removeClass("grayscale").fadeTo(400,1);
              setTimeout(function () {
                  if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                      $(_this).popover("hide");
                  }
              }, 200);
        });
      });
      
      function getPopContent(target) {
          
          return $("#" + target + "-content").html();
      };
});
```

```html
//Creating Calendar in JS
```

Comment: hi there is an error in your question snippet, but Iooking at your code it seems you are trying to access a scope that has changed in your getPopContent function

Comment: instead of  getPopContent($(this).prop("id")); try var x = $(this).prop("id"); getPopContent(x)

Comment: @jidexl21 i tried that.. i have done console.log() to check values. they are coming through fine. But the popover content divs remain empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the above issue with @jidexl21 suggestion.

Instead of: return getPopContent(id_current)
I used:
var content = getPopContent(id_current)
return content;